# Importing your data into MongoDB Atlas

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql, importerror

Trying to import a JSON file

Mongodb Version -- V3.6.3

Shell Version 3.6

Using this command to connect to cluster and import

```
mongoimport --host cluster0-shard-00-00-xxm0e.mongodb.net:24537 --db ny --type json --file C:/data/docs/ny.json --jsonArray --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username xyz --password mongodb
```

error message

```
2018-03-03T22:53:45.477-0800    no collection specified
2018-03-03T22:53:45.478-0800    using filename 'ny' as collection
2018-03-03T22:53:46.062-0800    Failed: error connecting to db server: server` returned error on SASL authentication step: bad auth Authentication failed.
2018-03-03T22:53:46.062-0800    imported 0 documents
```

Have tried a few options like
removing -ssl
adding ----sslAllowInvalidCertificates
Adding " C:/data/docs/ny.json" to file name 
and none of these works.. Any help appreciated

Comment: For Atlas support, please click on the `Support` button in the left sidebar. This will show you the documentations, and also allow you to log support cases if necessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to specify the collection `-c or --collection` flag. see official [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/).

```
mongoimport 
  --host <HOST> 
  --ssl --username <USERNAME> 
  --password <PASSWORD> 
  --authenticationDatabase admin 
  --db <DATABASE> 
  --collection <COLLECTION> 
  --type <FILETYPE> 
  --file <FILENAME>
```

Answer (score 3):

For now, we can easy import/export without having to have multiple options like this:

```
mongoimport --uri mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@your-cluster.mongodb.net/<DATABASE_NAME> --collection <COLLECTION> --type <FILETYPE> --file <FILENAME>

mongoexport --uri mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@your-cluster.mongodb.net/<DATABASE_NAME> --collection <COLLECTION> --type <FILETYPE> --out <FILENAME>
```

You also can found these on `Your Cluster > Cmd Line Tools`

Answer (score 2):

You missed specifying the collection name :

```
mongoimport --host cluster0-shard-00-00-xxm0e.mongodb.net:24537 --db ny --collection <entercollectionName> --type json --file C:/data/docs/ny.json --jsonArray --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username xyz --password mongodb
```

try the command now